# Как исключить gradle зависимость из другого модуля?

Tags: android, gradle

Есть модуль data, подключенный в presentation. Data модуль в gradle содержит зависимость на зависимость retrofit. Данная зависимость требуется только ему, но так же подтягивается в presentation. Есть способ исключить ее? Пробовал как api, так и implementation вариант.

Вообще архитектура состоит из 3 модулей. data, domain и presentation. В Presentation подключены Data и Domain. В Data подключен Domain. Domain сам по себе.

Comment: пока не избавите presentation от зависимости на data не получится.

Comment: implementation должен делать то, что вам нужно. А вообще  presentation не должен знать о data